# Find which series is selected by user using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel line chart with multiple series, the user would manually select a series and then click a button on my userform to choose one of the many custom colors which I have put on the userform so that color of the series can be changed to that chosen color.

I am struggling to detect which series is selected by the user in Excel VBA. Looks like isSelected property is not there.

In the below code variable ch is set to Activechart on Excel sheet

```
    For intSeriesCount = 1 To ch.SeriesCollection.Count
           
        If ch.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).isSelected = True Then
            ch.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = lblSelectedColor.BackColor
        End If
    Next
```

If you can point towards how to find out which series is selected by the user, that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the `Name` property of the selected Series equals the name of each Series in the loop e.g.

```
For intSeriesCount = 1 To ch.SeriesCollection.Count
    If ch.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Name = Selection.Name Then
        ch.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = lblSelectedColor.BackColor
    End If
Next
```

You do though need to ensure that the user has selected a Series otherwise this code may error, for example `If TypeName(Selection) = "Series" Then`

Comment: That helps.  Is there a way to do the same thing for Column and Bar chart as well?

Comment: The same `If` test works, you just need to adjust the line that changes the formatting to use the `Fill` property of the `Format` object instead of the `Line` property eg `ch.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lblSelectedColor.BackColor`

Comment: Happy to help. If you feel this answer (or any other) solved the problem for you, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the type of `Selectoin` with `TypeName` first, then you can find the series by matching `Selection.Name`.

```
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Series" Then
        For Each oSer In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            For intSeriesCount = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
                If ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Name = Selection.Name Then
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(intSeriesCount).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = lblSelectedColor.BackColor
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Debug.Print "Selection is NOT a series."
    End If
```